# Why SHCreateItemFromIDList faild?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

```
    TCHAR Temp[MAX_PATH] = { 0, };
    HRESULT hr = NULL;
    PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE pidl; //=LPITEMIDLIST
    IShellItem2 *_psiDrop=NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED | COINIT_DISABLE_OLE1DDE); //must add this!
    SHParseDisplayName(L"C:\\", NULL, &pidl, 0, NULL);
    if (SHGetPathFromIDList(pidl, Temp))
    {
        wprintf(L"%s\n", Temp);
    }
    hr = SHCreateItemFromIDList(pidl, IID_PPV_ARGS(&_psiDrop));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        wprintf(L"SHCreateItemFromIDList failed");
    }
```

how can i  initialize IShellItem2 to use PIDLIST_ABSOLUTE ?
_psiDrop has been NULL.

Comment: We don't know what `SHPathToPidl` is. We also don't know, which other operations in your code fail or succeed, or what the input data to `SHCreateItemFromIDList` is.

Comment: sorry, SHPathToPid is same with SHParseDisplayName, i  found SHPathToPidl  just before and now i chage "SHPathToPidl(L"C:\\", &pidl); " to  "SHParseDisplayName(L"C:\\", NULL, &pidl, 0, NULL);"
but it still does not initialize _psiDrop

Comment: Please update your question with the information, and make it a [mcve]. Also add information on the return values, and the contents of variables before and after each function call (where appropriate).

Comment: I solved it.... I reference this url https://svn.zive.ca/master/ShellItemTest/trunk/ShellItemTest/ShellItemTest.cpp, and found HRESULT faild values "CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED "
I first got to know HRESULT can return these values.....
CO_E_NOTINITIALIZED  means initialize COM lib.....
Im sorry about insincere question and my terrible english skill.
thank you for your interest.

Comment: That's why you **always** want to provide a [mcve], and check for return values. Either bit of information would have been enough for anyone around here to immediately spot the bug.